# 'ls' Command Failed to Execute via C in Linux

Tags: c, linux

This simple program supposed to run the command `ls`
but the output is 1 and 2.Can someone explain to me why `ls` not working ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int pid,stat;
    if((pid=fork())==0)
      {
        execl("/bin/","ls",NULL);
        printf("1");
    exit(1);
      }
    else
      {
         wait(&stat);
         printf("2");
      }
}
```

Comment: Got a Lesson: Little Knowledge is Dangerous. (I had to delete the comment.:) )

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);
           ^^^^
```

Comment: `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *)NULL);` actually.

Comment: @melpomene Why cast `NULL` ?! o.0

Comment: Because `execl` is a vararg function (so there is no specific type context) and `NULL` could be defined as plain `0`. This would pass an integer zero instead of a null pointer. It depends on the platform whether this difference actually causes runtime errors, but `(char *)NULL` is the technically correct way to do it.

Comment: @AsafShay Replace `printf("1")` by `perror("execl()")`. What output do you get?

Comment: @melpomene I stand corrected, the standard itself casts `0` to `char *` in the examples.

Comment: sorry ,execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL); does work but yesterday from what i remember it doesnt work.tanks all

Comment: now i have another problem if i want to add parametr
execl("/bin/date", "-u", NULL);
it doesnt make the command date -u
what is the problem ?

Comment: @AsafShay `execl("/bin/date", "date", "-u", NULL);`. Or maybe it's `/usr/bin/date` instead of `/bin/date`.

Comment: @AsafShay Sorry, you've just reached you quota for this question.